# SAPUI5: Refreshing table contents after oData.read

Tags: sapui5

Im building an application with two textboxes, a button and a table. On pressing the button, an array of filters is composed from the contents of the textboxes and sent to my oData service in a read request. Right now, when one record is returned (as it shows in the console), the table will not be updated. What am I missing?

This is the table:

```html
<Table id="PLTab" items="{/ORDSET}">
  <headerToolbar>
    <Toolbar>
      <Title text="Planned Orders" level="H2" />
    </Toolbar>
  </headerToolbar>
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Product" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Planned Order" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Production Planner" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <items>
    <ColumnListItem>
      <cells>
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{Maktx}" text="{Matnr}" />
        <Text text="{Ordno}" />
        <Text text="{Name}" />
      </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
  </items>
</Table>
```

And this is the relevant part of the controller:

```js
onInit: function() {
    var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("path");
    oModel.refresh(true);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  },


  openOrders: function(oEvent) {
    var PLFilters = [];
    PLFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter({
      path: "Matnr",
      operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
      value1: this.getView().byId("Product").getValue()
    }));
    PLFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter({
      path: "Locno",
      operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
      value1: this.getView().byId("Location").getValue()
    }));


    var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("path");
    oModel.read("/ORDSET", {
      filters: PLFilters,
      success: function(oData, oResponse) {
        console.log(oData);
      }
    });
  }
```

Thanks & regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

```
var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("path");
```

You use the model named "path" to read data, but in your XML View you use the default model (unnamed).

Try to change to

```
var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
```